# Is it possible to turn on video in Discord.JS?

Tags: discord, discord.js

In Discord.JS, or really any Discord library, is it possible to turn on your video or screen share in a voice channel? This could be used for a great deal of things, but I'm specifically thinking about screen sharing lyrics to songs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately it's not possible at the moment. The Discord API itself does not give bots the ability to screenshare, nor is it a feature in discord.js or any other discord library.

I'm not sure why they decided not to allow bots to screenshare, or if they plan on adding the possibility to do so in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use discord.js to screenshare, but if you use userbot, you can do it.

Why discord not allow bots to screenshare? Because they said security breach happens.